Arbitrary bitstrings
I was going to approach this question using the pigeonhole method and need to confirm if it's correct.
Given a bitstring B = b1, …, b1200 of length 1200, we need to prove that B contains at least two identical 10-bit substrings. Specifically, we want to demonstrate that there are distinct indices i, j ∈ {1, ..., 1191} such that:
bi, bi+1, ..., bi+9 = bj, bj+1, ..., bj+9.
 This is what I thought: since there are 1191 possible starting positions for 10-bit substrings in B (from position 1 to 1191). Each 10-bit substring has 2^10 (1024) unique possible combinations. so if I use the pigeonhole principle, if we have 1191 positions and only 1024 unique possibilities, at least two of these 10-bit substrings must be identical.

Your argument makes sense to me.

Correct. There are 1024 distinct 10-bit strings, so a set of 1191 10-bit strings must have duplicates. I don't think you even have to refer to the pigeonhole principle for that.
